# Can't use admin_enqueue_scripts or wp_enqueue_script

Tags: theme-development, admin

I've suddenly had an issue that neither `admin_enqueue_scripts` or `wp_register_script` are working properly, they were working fine for a while but suddenly stopped working.

In the following function, the first `wp_register_script` is working fine and loading modernizr, and the `wp_enqueue_style` is working fine and loading globalstyle, but neither the require or the global scripts are loading.

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/js/modernizr.js');

    wp_register_script('require', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/js/vendor/requirejs/require.js', array(), false, true);

    wp_register_script('global', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/js/global.js', array('require'), false, true);

    wp_enqueue_style('globalstyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/css/global.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts');
```

And the following function doesn't load admin-nav.js using `admin_enqueue_scripts()`

```
function navigation_script() {
    wp_register_script('admin-nav', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/js/admin-nav.js',array(), null, true);    
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'navigation_script' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your error is that you forgot to enqueue them,

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/js/modernizr.js');
    wp_register_script('require', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/js/vendor/requirejs/require.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_register_script('global', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/js/global.js', array('require'), false, true);      
    wp_register_style('globalstyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/css/global.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( array('modernizr','require','global') );
    wp_enqueue_style ('globalstyle');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts');

function navigation_script() {
    wp_register_script('admin-nav', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . '/js/admin-nav.js',array(), null, true);

    wp_enqueue_script('admin-nav');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'navigation_script' );
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I removed `wp_enqueue_script` in the process of trial & error, and now after adding it back, it didn't work at first, but then it turned out that somebody from my team removed `wp_footer()` from footer.php :/ Oh well... Thanks a lot though

Comment: @Karim you don't have to register and enqueue a script. If you are not enqueueing conditionally, you can just enqueue your scripts/styles :)